# WPF - How to set an element into a row by row tag, not row index

Tags: c#, wpf, row

I'm looking for a way to do the `SetRow(UIElement element, int value)` method, but instead of using an int value to place the element, it uses a row's tag to find the specific row.

Basically like this:

```
 RowDefinition newRow = new RowDefinition();
 newRow.Tag = "This is the row I want to find";
 TextBlock newBlock = new TextBlock();
 Grid.SetRow(newBlock, "This is the row I want to find");
```

And then it will find that row based on the tag and put the textblock in there. Is there a preexisting method that does this, or does anyone have any ideas on how to make a custom method for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `newRow` and `newBlock` have already been added to the same Grid, you can do this

```
var rowTag = "This is the row I want to find";

if (newBlock.Parent is Grid grid)
{
    var row = grid.RowDefinitions.FirstOrDefault(r => rowTag.Equals(r.Tag));

    if (row != null)
    {
        Grid.SetRow(newBlock, grid.RowDefinitions.IndexOf(row));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static class GridExtensor
{

    //This methods requires an element currently added to a grid.

    public static void SetRow(UIElement element, object rowTag)
    {
        var prt = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(element);
        if (prt != null && prt is Grid grid)
            SetRow(element, grid, rowTag);
    }

    public static void SetColumn(UIElement element, object columnTag)
    {
        var prt = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(element);
        if (prt != null && prt is Grid grid)
            SetColumn(element, grid, columnTag);
    }

    public static void SetRow(UIElement element, Grid grid, object rowTag)
    {
        var idx = grid.RowDefinitions.FirstIndexWhere(row => row.Tag.Equals(rowTag));

        Grid.SetRow(element, idx != -1 ? idx : 0);
    }

    public static void SetColumn(UIElement element, Grid grid, object columnTag)
    {
        var idx = grid.ColumnDefinitions.FirstIndexWhere(column => column.Tag.Equals(columnTag));
        Grid.SetColumn(element, idx != -1 ? idx : 0);
    }

    public static void SetRowAndAdd(UIElement element, Grid grid, object rowTag)
    {
         SetRow(element, grid, rowTag)
         if(!grid.Children.Contains(element))
             grid.Children.Add(element);
    }

    public static void SetColumnAndAdd(UIElement element, Grid grid, object columnTag)
    {
         SetColumn(element, grid, columnTag);
         if(!grid.Children.Contains(element))
             grid.Children.Add(element);
    }



    public static int FirstIndexWhere<TSource>(this IList<TSource> source, Func<TSource, bool> predicate)
    {
        if (source is null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));
        }
        if (predicate is null)
            return 0;
        int i = 0;
        foreach (var element in source)
        {
            if (predicate(element))
            {
                return i;
            }
            i++;
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```

usage:

```
RowDefinition newRow = new RowDefinition();
newRow.Tag = "This is the row I want to find";
TextBlock newBlock = new TextBlock();

//options
currentGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(newRow); // important!!
currentGrid.Children.Add(newBlock); //important!!!!
GridExtensor.SetRow(newBlock, "This is the row I want to find");
//or
GridExtensor.SetRowAndAdd(newBlock, currentGrid, "This is the row I want to find");
//or
currentGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(newRow); // important!!
GridExtensor.SetRow(newBlock, currentGrid, "This is the row I want to find");
currentGrid.Children.Add(newBlock);
```